# How to disable connection pooling with PostgreSQL in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to use [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [pgbouncer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) as an external connection pooler with my flask app. The [flask-sqlalchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/index.html) extension does not seem to expose a way to change the connection pooler to [NullPool](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool). Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to disable the flask-sqlalchemy connection pooling? Even with pgpool or pgbouncer (I'd opt for pgbouncer if you don't need pgpool) it is still a good idea to have local connection pooling as well. Just configure pgbouncer to pool based on transactions and it won't matter anyhow :)

Comment: In my case pgbouncer runs on the same machine as my flask app. So it seems inefficient to do connection pooling twice - once in the flask app and again in pgbouncer. I expect that creating a local TCP connection to pgbouncer is fast. For example - https://github.com/kljensen/async-flask-sqlalchemy-example#warnings-i-lied-it-actually-does-block - suggests that NullPool can be used, but I am not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it should be possible with the [apply_driver_hacks](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html?highlight=pool#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.apply_driver_hacks) method, I would strongly recommend against it.

The TCP overhead is negligible on a local machine, but the authentication and negotiation (encoding for example) certainly isn't. Keeping a pool is always useful within Flask and if needed can be configured with the `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE`, `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT`, `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE` and `SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW` [settings](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html?highlight=pool#configuration-keys).

If you simply want to cut down on overhead (albeit completely negligible) and your one instance Flask app is the only thing connecting to Postgres, than removing PgBouncer/PgPool from the mix would be better.